# Append a value to attribute "header" on a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, html-table

I'm working with a multilevel headers' table and I need to append a value dynamically a value to the attr "header" on the data cell "td". I append row by row on the table and the header on the left of the each row receives its id dynamically. here's the code of on line of the table that will be appended

```
<table>
    <tbody>
         <tr id="CacTabLine" class="cacTabLine" style="display: none">
            <th class="leftHeader">
                 <button type="buton"></button>
            </th>
            <td class="tdTotUsrA" headers="usrStud totUsrStu">
                 <p class="centro totUsrA"></p>
            </td>
            </td>
        </tr>   
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and the jquery that should add the attribute

```
var $cl = $("#cloneCacTabLine").clone();
var schoolId ="school-"+id;
$cl.find(".leftHeader").attr("id", schoolId);
$cl.find(".tdTotUsrA").attr("headers", $(this).attr("headers")+ " "+ schoolId );
```

I'm gettin:

```
<td class="tdTotUsrA" headers="undefined school-1092">
        </td>
```

I wish to get this

```
<td class="tdTotUsrA" headers="usrStud totUsrStu school-id">
```

I searched in jquery documentation and here in the forum e didn't find nothing the helped.

tnks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `this` in the place you have, because that refers to an instance of an undefined Javascript object at this point.
Perhaps define the headers you wish to add first and bind it to a variable to keep things neat. Then append them. eg:

```
let oldHeaders = $cl.find(".tdTotUsrA").attr("headers");
let newHeaders = oldHeaders + " " + schoolId;
$cl.find(".tdTotUsrA").attr("headers", newHeaders );
```

Comment: No problem! Please mark my answer as correct :) @PedroFernandesMartins

Comment: sorry bout that, i'm new here!